# Mobile Safari/Chrome page refresh from cache after inactivity

Tags: javascript, ios, iframe, mobile-safari

Our dynamic page is a wrapper for another web application that's being controlled through a Javascript API. There are settings being set through the script when the page loads before the other web app launches. The end result is an iFrame with the contents from the other app.

Problem: if I open another app on iPhone/iPad, do some work and come back to Safari or Chrome in a few minutes, I will see the page refreshed on the screen seemingly from cache with the contents of the iFrame also refreshed (most likely reloaded from the server) but without any of the original settings. I was wondering if it's possible to detect this behavior and force the page to reload completely?